# Ruby string with quotes for shell command args?

Tags: ruby, string, shell, escaping

Hi I need to create string like this:

```
drawtext="fontfile=/Users/stpn/Documents/Video_Experiments/fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf:text='content':fontsize=100:fontcolor=red:y=h/2"
```

I want to do something like

```
str = Q%[drawtext="fontfile=/Users/stpn/Documents/Video_Experiments/fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf:text='content':fontsize=100:fontcolor=red:y=h/2"]
```

I am getting this:

```
=> "drawtext=\"fontfile=/Users/stpn/Documents/Video_Experiments/fonts/Trebuchet_MS.ttf:text='content':fontsize=100:fontcolor=red:y=h/2\""
```

The escape characters after equals sign in drawtext="  is what I want to get rid of.. How to achieve that?

The string is to be used in a command line args.

Comment: The Ruby shell escapes the quote character for you when inspecting the value. Try `puts str`, which will print the string exactly as it is. I think it is already in the form you need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like many languages, Ruby needs a way of delimiting a quoted quote, and the enclosing quotes.

What you're seeing is the escape character which is a way of saying *literal* quote instead of syntactic quote:

```
foo = 'test="test"'
# => "test=\"test\""
```

The escape character is only there because double-quotes are used by default when inspecting a string. It's stored internally as a single character, of course. You may also see these in other circumstances such as a CR+LF delimited file line:

```
"example_line\r\n"
```

The `\r` and `\n` here correspond with carriage-return and line-feed characters. There's several of these characters defined in ANSI C that have carried over into many languages including Ruby and JavaScript.

When you output a string those escape characters are not displayed:

```
puts foo
test="test"
```